# How to correctly size bets when the probability of an event occurring is unknown?

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

I have studied the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) in relation to bet-sizing based on positive expected value (EV) events. However, I can't figure out a way to adapt it to solve the following problem:

Let's say we have event $A$ paying $5$ decimal odds, i.e., bet $\$1$, receive $\$5$ back (profit $\$4$), but we know the probability of the event occurring is $> 0.2$.

That is the only information we have. We know the event is positive EV, the extent to which is unknown. To reduce variance, betting less on lower-probability/higher-odd events seems to be a goal.

Do any bet-sizing strategies exist to fit this information? I've considered simply linearly/exponentially reducing bet-size as a function of higher decimal odds.

Comment: what is 5 dollar decimal odds, please define. Is it you get 5 after betting 1 when you win? 5 net or 4 net?

Comment: 4 net profit, bet $1, recieve 5 back, thanks!

Comment: See the article by Aldous and Bruss, Gambling under unknown probabilities as proxy for real world decisions under uncertainty, American Math Monthly 130 #4 April 2023 303-320.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what an awesome paper, perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really answer this question completely, I think, without having some idea (like a prior probability distribution) of how the win probability $p=\frac{1}{5}+\alpha$ is distributed for $\alpha \in (0,4/5].$

Armed with this information you could apply an optimization, by maximizing an appropriate criterion, possibly subject to some constraints.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, use the approximate value of $\alpha$ to compute $p$ or if you have distributional information compute $Q(p)$ the probability distribution of $p.$ Let $\overline{p}$ be the mean computed from $Q(p)$ or the approximate $p.$ Then one approach would be to bet the fraction given by Kelly criterion thus:
$$
f^{\ast}=\overline{p}-\frac{1-\overline{p}}{b}
$$
with $b=4,$ the proportion of net win to amount wagered. To be more aggressive I suppose you could use $\overline{p}$ to be the say $q-$th quantile instead of the mean with $q=0.6,$ for example. Or since the median is a bit less sensitive to noisy information take $\overline{p}$ to be the median instead of the mean.

Comment: Interesting, given I have data about approximate alpha, and then binary win/loss outcomes, how may I model/view this distribution?

Comment: Interesting, I've had a go at using Markov chain Monte Carlo to approximate a beta distribution for alpha. I think alpha defines "edge" in this setup: (1/odds) * (1 + alpha).

This has approximated an alpha with mean 0.125, std deviation 0.05, does this provide any useful information?

Comment: Note because p is distributed over (0, 1), this use of kelly results in it very quickly blowing the bankroll!